# Can't plant the spike in VALORANT

Tags: technical-issues, valorant

I've just started playing *VALORANT*, and I've run into an issue I haven't had before yet (I know my experience is pretty low, but still a new issue for me).

Before today, I could plant the spike fine; it worked in previous matches and in the tutorial. However, I can no longer plant the spike. I can pick it up and equip it, but I can't actually place it.

I take out the spike using '4', and then I hold down 4 to plant it. I also tried holding down 'f', because that's the button to interact with objects in my keybinds, but nothing happened (I did some research and found out that ["The spike can only be planted in a particular area of the bomb site"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjLsoavxMyDAxUhEEQIHdDBB-QQFnoECBIQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsenpai.gg%2Fblog%2Fbeginners-guide-valorant-spike%2F&usg=AOvVaw3QGYH0XMUj_kkR0N6OUzhE&opi=89978449), but I tried to plant the spike where another member on my team had planted it, and it didn't work; it played the 'plant spike' sound a couple seconds after I tried to plant it, but it wasn't actually planted, so that's probably not it).

A Reddit post claimed that they couldn't place the spike in  ["high ping matches"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjLsoavxMyDAxUhEEQIHdDBB-QQFnoECBoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2FValorantPBE%2Fcomments%2Fvf0y4m%2Fbug_cant_plant_spike_in_high_ping_matches_tested%2F&usg=AOvVaw1in5oqeRtp1DkU_iq0Rgav&opi=89978449), but that's probably not it either, because my ping is fine.
Thanks for any help.

*As a side note (somewhat related to the above question), how do you know if an area has been designated for someone to plant the spike? Does it have some blue outline on the floor around it or something?*

Comment: I haven't played Valorant in a long time but I believe there is some kind of visual thing on your HUD that tells you you can plant, or perhaps an area marked on the ground?

Comment: @Tas I figured out how to check if something is marked for a plant spike. First of all, you can only plant in A or B sites (these areas will be marked in yellow on the minimap. They will also have a faint blue aura around them.